# Is there any way to set the width of the dropdown in the DevExpress ComboBoxEdit for Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm using a DevExpress ComboBoxEdit to select a string.  Some of the strings are very long, so they take up the entire width of the screen, which works, but it's quite ugly.  I'd much rather have a dropdown which is a fixed width, which either shows the full text when I hover over the item, or once it has been selected.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look under ComboBoxEdit.Properties, there is a PopupFormSize and PopupFormMinSize properties you can set.

**Update:**

Got it to work, but you have to set `ComboBoxEdit.Properties.PopupSizable = true` and handle the `QueryPopUp` event:

```
private void comboBoxEdit1_QueryPopUp(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  ComboBoxEdit cb = (ComboBoxEdit)sender;
  PropertyInfo pi = typeof(RepositoryItem).GetProperty("PropertyStore", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
  HybridDictionary store = (HybridDictionary)pi.GetValue(cb.Properties, null);
  store["ComboPopupSize"] = new Size(100, 100);
}
```

Comment: I only have "PopupFormMinSize"... maybe I have an old version of DevExpress?  I'm using version 8.2.

Comment: @Lost I'm using v11.1, but there seems to be problems setting it: [ComboBox DropDown Width](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q93205.aspx)

Comment: @Lost I updated the answer with how DevExpress suggested to do it.  A bit of a turd.

Comment: FieldInfo fi is not used here. I guess it can safely be removed from the code.